# cannot find symbol : class NumberTools

Tags: java, lucene

I don't know java. I am trying to compile a plugin for Bamboo using eclipse. I get java compilation error. Please help me identify/fix this issue.

JmeterResultsWriter.java looks like this

```
  ##########################JmeterResultsWriter.java ##################

    package com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.jmeter_aggregator.index;

    import java.util.Map;

    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.NumberTools;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Index;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

    import com.atlassian.bamboo.index.CustomPostBuildIndexWriter;
    import com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.jmeter_aggregator.builder.JmeterBuildDataHelper;
    import com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.jmeter_aggregator.Sampler;
    import com.atlassian.bamboo.resultsummary.BuildResultsSummary;
    import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

    public class JmeterResultsWriter implements CustomPostBuildIndexWriter
    {
        public static final String JMETER_AGGREGATOR_NINETY_PERECENT = "jmeter.aggregator.ninety.percent";
        public static final String JMETER_AGGREGATOR_MEDIAN = "jmeter.aggregator.median";
        public static final String JMETER_AGGREGATOR_THROUGHPUT = "jmeter.aggregator.throughput";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void updateIndexDocument(@NotNull Document doc, @NotNull BuildResultsSummary summary)
        {
            Map<String, String> data = summary.getCustomBuildData();
            String xmlData = data.get(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_MAP);
            if (xmlData != null)
            {
                String xmlTotal = data.get(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_TOTAL);
                XStream xstream = new XStream();
                Sampler sampler = (Sampler) xstream.fromXML(xmlTotal);

                // Store the total and xmldata unindexed.
               doc.add(new Field(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_MAP, xmlData, Store.COMPRESS, Index.NO));
               doc.add(new Field(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_TOTAL, xmlTotal, Store.COMPRESS,
                  Index.NO));
    }
      }
       }

    ################### JmeterResultsReader.java ###################
      package com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.jmeter_aggregator.index;

      import java.util.Map;

      import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
      import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;

      import com.atlassian.bamboo.index.CustomIndexReader;
      import com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.jmeter_aggregator.builder.JmeterBuildDataHelper;
      import com.atlassian.bamboo.resultsummary.BuildResultsSummary;

      public class JmeterResultsReader implements CustomIndexReader
      {

           public void extractFromDocument(Document doc, BuildResultsSummary summary)
           {
                Map<String, String> results = summary.getCustomBuildData();
                Field dataField = doc.getField(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_MAP);
                if (dataField != null)
                {
                    results.put(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_MAP, dataField.stringValue());
                }
                Field totalField = doc.getField(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_TOTAL);
                if (totalField != null)
                {
                   results.put(JmeterBuildDataHelper.CUSTOM_BUILD_DATA_TOTAL, totalField.stringValue());
                }
            }
       }
```

---

[ERROR] /C:/Users/twinnarasi/workspace/atlassian-bamboo-jmeter-aggregator/src/main/java/JmeterResultsWriter.java:[7,34] C:\Users\twinnarasi\workspace\atlassian-bamboo-jmeter-aggregator\src\main\java\JmeterResultsWriter.java:7: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class NumberTools
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.lucene.document

---

ERROR] /C:/Users/twinnarasi/workspace/atlassian-bamboo-jmeter-aggregator/src/main/java/com/atlassian/bamboo/plugins/jmeter_aggregator/index/JmeterResultsReader.java:[23,40] C:\Users\twinnarasi\workspace\atlassian-bamboo-jmeter-aggregator\src\main\java\com\atlassian\bamboo\plugins\jmeter_aggregator\index\JmeterResultsReader.java:23: incompatible types
[ERROR] found   : org.apache.lucene.index.IndexableField
[ERROR] required: org.apache.lucene.document.Field

Comment: You are using a source that works with Apache Lucene 3.x, but you have Apache Lucene 4.x. They are not compatible.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.. But we are using Lucene 4.x for Bamboo 5.7 and we cannot downgrade to 3.x. Originally we are trying to compile the JMeter Aggregator plugin (it was supported by bamboo only until 5.5.1) so I think I have to modify the Jmeteraggregator's pom.xml to be compatible with 4.x

Comment: I don't think it's just a question of pom.xml - this source directly imports `org.apache.lucene.document.NumberTools`, which does not exist in Lucene 4.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, you are using code written for Lucene 3.X, when you are using Lucene 4.X.  `NumberTools` was removed in 4.0 (and had been deprecated since 2.9, maybe earlier).

For numeric fields, you should use the appropriate type of field, rather than getting up to anything fancy with transforming it yourself.  A `LongField`, or `IntField`, for instance.

If you really must go transforming the values yourself, [`NumericUtils`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html) replaces the functionality of the old `NumberTools`.  So instead of:

```
string s = NumberTools.longToString(longval);
//index the string...
```

You will instead do something like:

```
BytesRef longvalRef = new BytesRef();
NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded(longval, 0, longvalRef);
//index the BytesRef...
```

You should really just use a `LongField` instead, though.  See the note on NumericUtils:

> NOTE: This API is for internal purposes only and might change in incompatible ways in the next release.

Which it certainly has, in 4.0 and 4.10, for instance.

I believe you may run into other problems in updating this code to 4.X.  Might do well to look over the [Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html).

Comment: I validate the project in eclipse and it reported that import org.apache.lucene.document.NumberTools; is not really used by the script. So i removed it. ALso I altered the following in both the reader and writer files and can compile it successfully now,

Comment: import org.apache.lucene.document.Field; = import org.apache.lucene.Index.IndexableField;
Field dataField = IndexableField dataField 
Field totalField = IndexableField totalField

Comment: JmeterResultsWriter.java" file 
Removed import org.apache.lucene.document.NumberTools; file